# mapping JSON data and sorting if for 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to map my data and sort *links* in 2 groups: favourite and non favourite .
For each item I need key and name as well.

here is the html structure:

```
<ul class="links-favourites"></ul>
<ul class="non-favourite-list">
    <li>Rest of your Links
        <ul class="non-favourite-inner"></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Data structure for 3 links - 2 favourites and 1 non-favourite:

```
[{
    "name": "favourite 1",
    "key": "WBwLrM7KkF2qbgRn847yLjJD0e0",
    "favourite": true
}, {
    "name": "favourite2",
    "key": "btB3pFs22S_cBvkCCiMTGWQRVUs",
    "favourite": true
}, {
    "name": "not favourite1",
    "key": "jTOdit6iEBZg8OYK9tOqdoeWYRo",
    "favourite": false
}]
```

Here is by buggy JS:

```
$.post("http://0.0.0.0:9292/api/stremes", function (data) {
    var names = data.map(function (i) {
        return i['streme'].name
    });
    var keys = data.map(function (i) {
        return i['streme']['key']
    });
    var favourites = data.map(function (i) {
        return i['streme']['favourite']
    });



    var containerFavourite = document.querySelector(".streme-favorites");
    var containerNoFavourite = document.querySelector(".non-favourite-inner");
    names.forEach(function (name) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = name;
        $(li).addClass("name");
        $(li).each(function (index) {
            $(this).data("favourite", favourites[index]);
            console.log(favourites[index]); // giving undefined
        });
        if ($(li).data("favourite", favourite[index]) == true) {
            $(this).addClass("favourite");
            containerFavourite.appendChild($(this));
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("no-favourite");
            containerNoFavourite.appendChild($(this));
        }
    });

    $(".name").each(function (index) {
        $(this).data("key", keys[index]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

why not iterate `data`? i.e. `data.forEach(function(e){...})` you can get more information inside the block,and `map`s are not necessary.

The complete code would be like:

```
data.forEach(function(e){
var name = e['streme']['name'];
var favourite = e['streme']['favourite'];
if(favourite){
//...
}else{
//...
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much cleaner looking  solution

```
    var $lists={ 'fav': $('.links-favourites'), 'noFav' :  $('.non-favourite-inner') };  

    $.each(data, function( idx, item){
        var isFav= item.favourite;
        var list= isFav ? 'fav' : 'noFav';
        $lists[list].append( createLI( item, isFav) );

    });


function createLI( obj, isFav){
    var favClass= isFav  ?'favourite' : 'no-favourite';
     var elemData={'favourite': obj, 'key': obj.key};
     return $('<li>',{ class: favClass}).data( elemData ).text( obj.name);
}
```

Some of your code is a bit confusing in that data doesn't match `stremes` and classes are slightly different in script than in html. But this should give you a good starting point. Also not sure what to do with `key` in markup, or what links are supposed to be

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KZmVn/4/)**</kbd>